# Making thinner edges in MATLAB with Image processing toolbox

Tags: matlab

After edges, I need to to erode the image lines to be thinner (to remove 1px from all strong lines):

I already tried:

```
H_skel=bwmorph(H1,'thin'); 

H_skel=bwmorph(H1,'thin',Inf);
```

Same with skel (skeletization) method.

Any examples/ideas how to do this?

Or if I use the erode function, how do I know what structure element I need to create?

Comment: Depends on the shape ob objects in your image I guess. What is not working with what you tried? Can you show pictures?

Comment: We need to see some pictures on what the input is and what the desired output is.  It's hard to visualize this without images (hence.... **image** processing).